# ClojureScript Quick-Start node_repl java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for char: -1

Tags: node.js, clojure, clojurescript

I follow [Quick-Start](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#nodejs-repl) to try Nodejs repl

```
$ cat node_repl.clj
(require 'cljs.repl)
(require 'cljs.build.api)
(require 'cljs.repl.node)

(cljs.build.api/build "src"
                      {:main 'hello-world.core
                       :output-to "out/main.js"
                       :verbose true})

(cljs.repl/repl (cljs.repl.node/repl-env)
                :watch "src"
                :output-dir "out")

$ cat src/hello_world/core.cljs
(ns hello-world.core
  (:require [clojure.nodejs :as nodejs]))

(nodejs/enable-util-print!)

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Hello world! 123"))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

When I run `rlwrap java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main node_repl.clj`, I got this error:

```
$ rlwrap java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main node_repl.clj
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/cljs/core.cljs to out/cljs/core.cljs
Reading analysis cache for jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/cljs/core.cljs
Compiling out/cljs/core.cljs
Using cached cljs.core out/cljs/core.cljs
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/cljs/nodejs.cljs to out/cljs/nodejs.cljs
Compiling out/cljs/nodejs.cljs
Compiling src/hello_world/core.cljs
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/base.js to out/goog/base.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/string/string.js to out/goog/string/string.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/object/object.js to out/goog/object/object.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/math/integer.js to out/goog/math/integer.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/string/stringbuffer.js to out/goog/string/stringbuffer.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/debug/error.js to out/goog/debug/error.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/dom/nodetype.js to out/goog/dom/nodetype.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/asserts/asserts.js to out/goog/asserts/asserts.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/array/array.js to out/goog/array/array.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/reflect/reflect.js to out/goog/reflect/reflect.js
Copying jar:file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/cljs.jar!/goog/math/long.js to out/goog/math/long.js
Copying file:/Users/liujiacai/codes/clojure/cls/src/hello_world/core.cljs to out/hello_world/core.cljs
ClojureScript Node.js REPL server listening on 55283
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for char: -1
        at clojure.lang.RT.charCast(RT.java:1052)
        at cljs.repl.node$read_response.invokeStatic(node.clj:49)
        at cljs.repl.node$setup.invokeStatic(node.clj:133)
        at cljs.repl.node.NodeEnv._setup(node.clj:192)
        at cljs.repl$repl_STAR_$fn__5113.invoke(repl.cljc:884)
        at cljs.compiler$with_core_cljs.invokeStatic(compiler.cljc:1154)
        at cljs.repl$repl_STAR_.invokeStatic(repl.cljc:871)
        at cljs.repl$repl.invokeStatic(repl.cljc:1037)
```

Is anything I am missing ?

Comment: Seems to work for me when I copy & paste your files. Is there anything else in your working directory and which Java version are you using? I'm on `java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)` OSX

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat Aha, I have both jdk7 and jdk8 installed on my Mac, and jdk7 is the default, when I changed to jdk8, everything work fine. Thank you so much.